# android Set text is not working for me

Tags: android, textview

I am trying get the weather details like temp and condition and I am unable to Display them But I am able to see them in my log cat code.

Here is my code follows

```
cond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condDescr);
 temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);
temp.setText("HI How are you");

JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{city});   

private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        try {
            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

            // Let's retrieve the icon
            //weather.iconData = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;

}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {         
        super.onPostExecute(weather);

        if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length); 
            //imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
        }


        String str1 = (weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescr() + ")");
        //temp.setText("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 273.15)) + "�C");**(I have tried this one too)**
        String str2 = ("" + weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
    Log.w("myApp", str1);
        Log.w("mytemp", str2);
        cond.setText(str1);
        temp.setText(str2);

        //temp.setText("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 273.15)) + "�C");

    }
```

My XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/but_wifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_start_wifi_on" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/but_start_gps"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_start_gps_on" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_mid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but_chooseTrack"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but_go"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:text="@string/bt_txt_go"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/but_start_gps"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tempText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/but_wifi"
        android:src="@drawable/weather" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I have also tried like manual data set but it is not working for me. I dont know what was my mistake could any one tell me how to solve this.

Comment: where you are calling `task.execute();` ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are unable to display them? Does the code cause a crash?

Comment: No I could able to see them on my mobile screen.

Comment: Is this code in an activity or fragment? What does the layout xml look like? Are you sure the TextView is on the screen?

Comment: It is in activity and My xml looks like above which I have posted now. Yes I have Textview on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call the method `doInBackground` of your ASyncTask, you need to add `task.execute(params)`. 
`params` can be either a `String` or multiple `Strings` separated by ,

In your case, you should pass to execute the data needed by the method getWeatherData().

Comment: I have actually called task.execute(params). Please see my Updated question.

Comment: you don't need to create a String[], you can pass directly "city". But that shouldn't be where your problem comes from

Comment: Ya code now is working perfectly I am see in the logcat ouput but I am unable view it on my screen. That is setText  is not working for me.